# AWS codepipeline doesn't update code when pushed to github

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS(codepipeline + code deploy) and I connected my github account.

At first run, I had a mistake so it failed. Then I fixed the code and pushed to github.  This caused the new pipeline to be triggered and I can see that pipeline can see new commit.

**Problem:**  Even though it sees the new commit, somehow code is still old in EC2 instance and it fails for the same reason it failed for the first time.

I don't even know how to debug this. I then removed the code from EC2(i connected it with ssh and removed the folder). Now, triggering the deployment still doesn't put the code again in the EC2 intance's folder.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are having a Permissions error or you don't have the CodeDeploy Agent installed on the EC2 instance. You can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html) starting from step 3.

You could also debug what's happening to your codepipline deployment. On the pipeline page, at the Deploy stage click the blue link for more information on your error. Or in Details

Comment: I just checked and codepipeline successfully brings changes from github and puts it in S3 bucket. I checked S3 bucket and it contains updated code. Problem seems like codedeploy doesn't take that from S3 to EC2. any idea ?

Comment: That's probalby the codepipeline artifact being stored on Codepipeline's S3 buket. Unless you configured your source stage to be triggered by an S3 Bucket, your issue is not there. Check the CodeDeploy agent on the EC2 instance and the pipeline errors if it has any

Comment: Codedeploy is installed welll. I just checked and it says `The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running as PID 5854`. Pipeline error just says: Script at specified location: scripts/application_stop.sh run as user ec2-user failed with exit code 1 View more and that's all it says

Comment: But is the code updated then or not? You said you deleted it and if the logs are showing that message means it was redeployed. Maybe your issue is not AWS but the code you are running

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).